# How to replace h:commandButton with a div

Tags: button, html, submit, commandlink

I want to replace all kind of buttons on my page with **div** as bellow:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="button_left"></div>
    <div class="button_center">save</div>
    <div class="button_right"></div>
</div>
```

I replace components onto **h:commandLink** and it work with most of them, 
except those like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="do it" action="#{myBean.myFirstAction()}" />
    <h:commandButton value="do that" action="#{myBean.mySecondAction()}" />
</h:form>
```

How to deal with it?

[edit]: **a4j:commandButton** is an example of component that work fine. The difference between those component is that **h:commandButton** ganerate **input type="submit"** and the rest generate **input type="button"**.

Comment: kindly also show the code of components which works fine after replace.

Comment: does those components have `action` attributes?